# MongoDB: $eq not working properly with $and?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "people_list": [
      {
        "gender": "female",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": true,
        "hobby": "soccer"
      },
      {
        "gender": "female",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": true,
        "hobby": "football"
      },
      {
        "gender": "female",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": true,
        "hobby": "basketball"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "people_list": [
      {
        "gender": "female",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": false,
        "hobby": "soccer"
      },
      {
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": true,
        "hobby": "football"
      },
      {
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 20,
        "adult": true,
        "hobby": "basketball"
      },

    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to iterate through the `people_list`, and check if all elements within can pass a certain criteria. So I plan to use `allElementsTrue`
The code would be like the following (Say I want to verify `adult` and `age` only):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $allElementsTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$people_list",
            as: "ppl",
            in: {
              $and: [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$ppl.adult",
                    true
                  ],
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$ppl.age",
                    20
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However, I still get both documents `"_id": "1"`, and `"_id": "2"` in the output, despite that `"_id": "2"`'s `people_list`'s first object's `adult` field is `false`!
Not sure why. Could anyone please give me some suggestions?

I've added the code into this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S4cHWGQXIOz) for your convenience. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$and` branches should be a separate objects while in your case it's one object so only first condition gets applied, try:

```
$and: [
    {
        "$eq": [
            "$$ppl.adult",
            true
        ]
    },
    {
        "$eq": [
            "$$ppl.age",
            20
        ]
    }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OKwIxIrCLn7)